# JS function that counts up to entered number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script that counts up to the entered number in an  field in HTML and makes an unordered list of every integer preceding it and also display whether it is even or odd.
I've tried something like this

```
<script>
    const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el")
    let ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el")
    let number = null

    inputEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let number = inputEl.value
        console.log(number)
    })

        function printNumbers(){
            for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++){
                if (i % 2 === 0){
                    ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + i + ": Even" + "</li>"
                    console.log(i)
                }
                else {
                    ulEl.innerHTML = "<li>" + i + ": Even" + "</li>"
                }
            }

        }
</script>
```

However the for loop gets stuck on 0, regardless of my input. Tried pushing i into a numbersArray but it always displayed 0

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function. So this has to be triggered when the button is clicked right? So you should call the function inside the event listener and pass the input value as an argument,

```
inputEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let number = inputEl.value
        printNumbers(number);
});
```

And add the parameter to your function now,

```
function printNumbers(number){
        for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++){
            if (i % 2 === 0){
                ulEl.innerHTML += "<li>" + i + ": Even" + "</li>"
                console.log(i)
            }
            else {
                ulEl.innerHTML = "<li>" + i + ": Even" + "</li>"
            }
        }

    }
```